# Shell script to get one to one map and rename the filename

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

I have 2 files sorted by numerically. I need help with shell script to read these 2 files and do a 1:1 mapping and rename the filenames with the mapped case#;

For example:

```
cat case.txt
10_80
10_90

cat files.txt
A BCD_x 1.pdf
A BCD_x 2.pdf

ls pdf_dir
A BCD_x 1.pdf A BCD_x 2.pdf
```

Read these 2 txt and rename the pdf files in pdf_dir :

```
A BCD_x 1.pdf as A BCD_10_80.pdf
A BCD_x 1.pdf as A BCD_10_90.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Bash 4.0 this could help:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A MAP
I=0
IFS=''

while read -r CASE; do
    (( ++I ))
    MAP["A BCD_x ${I}.pdf"]="A BCD_${CASE}.pdf"
done < case.txt

while read -r FILE; do
    __=${MAP[$FILE]}
    [[ -n $__ ]] && echo mv "$FILE" "$__"  ## Remove echo when things seem right already.
done < files.txt
```

Note: Make sure you run the script in UNIX file format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste` to create the "mapping", then shell facilities to do the renaming.

```
shopt -s extglob
while IFS=$'\t' read file replacement; do
    echo mv "$file" "${file/x +([0-9])/$replacement}"
done < <(paste files.txt case.txt)
```

remove "echo" when you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}
  {f=$0; sub(/_x /, "_" a[FNR] " "); system("mv \"" f "\" \"" $0 "\"")}' case.txt files.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using normal array and sed substitution - 
Removing echo before mv will provide you the move capability. 
You can change the /path/to/pdf_dir/ to specify your path to desired directory

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line
do
    arr[i]="$line"
  ((i=i+1));
done < files.txt

i=0
while read case
do
   newFile=$(echo "${arr[i]}" | sed "s/x/"$case"/")
   echo mv /path/to/pdf_dir/"${arr[i]}" /path/to/pdf_dir/"$newFile"
   ((i=i+1))
done < case.txt
```